# Qt5.2.1 : error: gl.h included before glew.h is NOT SOLVED

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have been trying to solve the widely known problem with including GLEW into Qt.And I still haven't succeeded.
Before people here start downvoting for repeating question; I actually went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580675/error-gl-h-included-before-glew-h) ,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479374/opengl-wih-qt5-error-gl-h-included-before-glew-h) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415319/fatal-error-gl-h-included-before-glew-h) SO post which explain the workaround.

1. I recompiled Qt 5.2.1 from sources using opengl desktop configs. Didn't help.
2. I put `glew.h` and Qt unrelated stuff into another header/cpp and it also didn't help.
3. I tried to include `glew.h` before my `#include <QGLWidget>` and it didn't work as well.The only case it does work is when I put `glew.h` at the top of `main.cpp` which is of course unacceptable in app design terms.

So I am asking what else can be done here? I know I can use Qt gl headers which supply GL function pointers just like GLEW but I **can't** do that as I have a lib linked to Qt which uses GLEW. Once I use that lib content I am getting all that mess with "`gl.h` included before `glew.h`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would including `<glew.h>` at the top of `main.cpp` be "unacceptable"? (hint: it's not)

It seems like you need to ensure that everywhere in your code, the `glew.h` header is included before Qt gets a chance to do that. I'd add it to my `global.h` style header and make sure to include that in every header in my project.

Comment: What is happening that even if I include glew.h at the very top of main.cpp ,if I then also include glew.h in another place like in the header of some widget before <GLWidget> it still throws that error.

Comment: Oops!Yeah,you are absolutely right.I have skiped #include <QtGui> which was included in another place above the problematic header with glew.h .Well....Really stupid miss.